# MigraDoc page break in middle of Text added by AddFOrmattedText

Tags: c#, migradoc

Im creating a PDF-Document with MigraDoc.
I added a full size "Header" to all Pages:

```
            Image bg = section.Headers.FirstPage.AddImage(@"\\server\header.bmp");
        bg.Height = "29.7cm";
        bg.Width = "21cm";
        bg.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Page;
        bg.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Page;
        bg.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through;
```

Now i want to add Text from a Textbox to that Page:

```
Paragraph paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
        paragraph.Format.SpaceBefore = "7.5cm";
        paragraph.Format.SpaceAfter = "5";
        paragraph.Format.Font.Color = Color.FromCmyk(100, 100, 100, 100);
        FormattedText ft = paragraph.AddFormattedText(this.gMailItem.Body);
```

The problem i have is that the text Im adding could be bigger than one page is. If this happens, the text is printed over the "full size header"/stationery.
Is there a way to limit the height of a Document (to force a page break)?

EDIT: Here is a picture of my problem: http://img4host.net/upload/1014244953be8611defa9.PNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "client area" of the document is defined by the page size and the margins (top, bottom, left, right) and MigraDoc will add page breaks when this area is full.

I do not fully understand what the problem is, but probably you have to increase the top margin (instead of setting SpaceBefore to 7.5 cm - SpaceBefore works only at the start of the paragraph while TopMargin works for each new page).

Edit: See also:
[Post in PDFsharp Forum](http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=3085#p3085)

Comment: I just added this Screenshot: http://img4host.net/upload/1014244953be8611defa9.PNG

Comment: @Daniel M: So the BottomMargin is too small. Increase the BottomMargin and the page break will occur earlier.